# Update value in dictionary for q lang (kdb+)

Tags: kdb, q-lang

**How I may update values in q dictionary use functional way?**

Example:

```
x: `1`2`3;
d: x!x;
show[d];
// d -> 
// 1 | 1
// 2 | 2
// 3 | 3
// TODO change d: 
show[d];
// d -> 
// 1 | 11
// 2 | 22
// 3 | 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may change you dictionary in this way:

```
// @[dictionary name; list of keys; ?; list of values];
@[d; `1`2; :; `11`22];
```

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to functionally update a dictionary with standard amend/set syntax (using ":") as follows:

```
q)x:1 2 3

q)d:x!x

q)d
1| 1
2| 2
3| 3

q)f:{d[x]:y}
q)f[2;7]

q)d
1| 1
2| 7
3| 3
```

This also works for vectors provided they are of the same length :

```
q)f[1 2;5 6]
q)d
1| 5
2| 6
3| 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
q)x:1 2 3;
q)d:x!x;
q)d
  1| 1
  2| 2
  3| 3
q)d,: enlist[2]!enlist[5];
q)d
  1| 1
  2| 5
  3| 3
q)d,: (2 3)!(7 7);
q)d
  1| 1
  2| 7
  3| 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple amend on the key you wish to change.

```
q)d[1 2]+:10
q)d
1| 11
2| 12
3| 3
```

This is the equivalent of

```
d[1 2]:d[1 2]+10
```

or

```
d[1 2]:11 12
```

Here there is no real need for a functional apply to change the values in the dictionary.